# How to install R on ubuntu 16.10 via the terminal?

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, terminal

I'm trying to install R from the terminal following this site:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-on-linux-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus/

When I execute `sudo apt-get install r-base`, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.3.2-1xenial0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.3.2-1xenial0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: You can also download it manually. There is a new release of R(6 mars 2017). You can find it here: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/yakkety/ It's work perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the two others to the command, and see the errors it generates, ie do

```
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-core r-recommended
```

You likely you have something installed which conflicts.  Many (and I mean *thousands*) of us run these packages just fine.

You can also consider the r-sig-debian mailing list.

Comment: I just tried the above command, this is what I got as an error:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: 16.10 is yakkety, you seem to be pointing at xenial aka 16.04 and getting one unresolved dependency.  I would try yakkety instead.  The [README.md at CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) has instructions -- just adapt for yakkety.

Comment: Thanks the link was perfect!

Comment: Glad to know it worked, and thanks for accepting the answer. You may also upvote (click on upward-facing triangle).